# Timer on Server Side?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, timer

I want to have a Timer to update the global variable like every 10 sec, so I put a timer in my Global.asax.cs:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer aTimer = new Timer();
    aTimer.Interval = 10*1000;
    aTimer.Tick += aTimer_Tick;            
    aTimer.Start();
}

void aTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update Data
}
```

But weird thing is nothing happen after 10 sec. I wonder if is possible to do it like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't running and you just don't see the results in the webpage? Try writing to a database table or text file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

The former uses `Elasped` as the event handler and will function as expected almost anywhere in an application. The latter is tailored for winforms and should be used on `Form1_Load()` not on application start.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the `Timer` object is destroyed after the `Application_Start` void is closed. So, try to assign it to an application variable.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET requests and events are not designed to take a long time.  You should consider writing a Windows Service, depending on what you're trying to achieve (what are you trying to achieve?).